# Select eliminando outro Select

Tags: php, sql

bom meu cenario é o seguinte, tenho 1 slide onde mostra as 4 ultimas noticias

```
SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE destacar='Destacado' ORDER BY idnoticia DESC LIMIT 4
```

embaixo do slide tenho uma lista das outras materias onde deve apresentar as nao marcada como NAO DESTACADO e as marcadas com DESTACADO a partir do 4º resultado, estou usando a seguinte consulta.

```
SELECT * FROM noticias n WHERE idnoticia NOT IN ( SELECT * FROM (SELECT idnoticia FROM noticias WHERE destacar = 'Destacado' ORDER BY idnoticia ASC LIMIT 10) p) ORDER BY idnoticia DESC LIMIT 9 OFFSET 4
```

esta funcionando em partes, esta listando a partir do 4º resultado porem se eu incluir uma noticia no meio(supondo que entre o 2º e 4º DESTACADO) marcado como NAO DESTACADO ela não aparece.

[image: exemplo]

Alguma forma de contornar esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem o banco em mãos fica complicado testar, mas teste dessa maneira, não precisa do `OFFSET` pois as 4 primeiras serão ignoradas no `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  noticias 
WHERE idnoticia NOT IN 
  (SELECT 
    idnoticia 
  FROM
    noticias 
  WHERE destacar = 'Destacado' 
  ORDER BY idnoticia DESC 
  LIMIT 4) 
ORDER BY idnoticia DESC 
LIMIT 9
```

Espero que ajude

Abraços